# How can I always get the coordinates inside the form in winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, coordinates

I want to get the form's coordinates X/Y even if the mouse is inside a control. To be more specific, if I move my mouse inside the form and the point of my mouse's location is (400,400), if I move inside a control I want the point's coordinates to change as if I was still moving my mouse inside the form, instead of changing to something like (15,30). I have tried using PointToClient or PointToScreen but nothing worked.

Edit:

For example, I have this method :

```
private void PlayScreen_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.X.ToString() + "," + e.Y.ToString();
        }

private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

In button1_MouseMove I want to update label1 with the same coordinates before my mouse moved in button1.

Comment: Care to show your existing handler?

Comment: I don't get the issue without seeing your code because this `private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", e.X, e.Y);
        }` works fine.

Comment: Do you mean to capture the Mouse Pointer position continuously or just is some situations? Meaning, when you explicitly trigger this functionality and, in the meanwhile, child Controls are not required to perform their usual actions? Are all child Controls required to return the Mouse Pointer location in relation to parent Form bounds or just a limited group (or a single one)?

Comment: @Wyck `e.Location` in `Control.MouseMove` gives you Mouse coordinates related to a Control client area, not to the parent Form's client area.

Comment: If just one control, is involved, you can use `Point formLocation = [YourControl].FindForm().PointToClient(MousePosition);` (in the `Control.MouseMove` handler)

Comment: @Jimi no,unfortunately if the coordinates of the mouses are (323,434) when the mouse enters the controls they show something like (389,512).

Comment: That code gives you the coordinates of the Mouse Pointer in relation to the Form's ClientRectangle. If you need different coordinate offsets, you need to be very specific on that.